# Sql stored procedure duration

Tags: sql-server

I am capturing Activity information on my sql server 2008r2 instance using a query like below(dmv's).

```
select
    der.session_id,
    der.blocking_session_id as isbeingblockedby,
    der.start_time,
    datediff(MINUTE, der.start_time,getdate()) as RunningForMinutes,
    datediff(SECOND, der.start_time,getdate() ) as RunningForSeconds,
    st.text as query text,     
from sysprocesses sp
full join sys.dm_exec_requests  der
    on sp.spid = der.session_id
full OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions des
    on der.session_id = des.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(der.sql_handle) st
--CROSS APPLY sydes.dm_exec_query_plan(deder.plan_handle) qp
```

Basically it shows blocking or locking information and what session_id's were running at a specific time(I run this every 10 seconds). I have recently been asked to get stored procedure duration. I was wondering if anyone has ever used DMV's running to capture this. I know I can use SQL server profiler but the business and even myself are concerned running this as it could degrade performance. I have executed my query in a continuous loop running every 500ms and this helps a little. But I wanted to get and share ideas from others on this

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    EXEC CaptureCurrentActvity;

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.500';
END
```

Comment: Stored procedure duration for all stored procedures or this one?

Comment: @Shaneis specific stored procedures on a database. Thanks

Comment: Maybe take a look at [dm_exec_procedure_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx)

Comment: @Shaneis ok thanks. I think that's only if it's cached.

Comment: Then might I suggest the wonder that is sp_WhoIsActive?

Comment: You might want to look into extended events

Comment: @Shaneis That's good but again needs to run continuously to get duration

Comment: @JamesZ extended events in 2008r2. Do you have any links for examples for setting it up. Thanks

Comment: @ADTJOB Sorry no I don't